# Running csstidy from Java

Tags: java, csstidy

I am trying to develop a Java tool to refactor css files. I am trying to access the command prompt from Java. The command prompt is opening fine but it's not running the csstidy exe file.

```
try {

  String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd C:/Users/BS11040/Desktop/CSSTIDY_JAVA/";

  Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

  OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();

  out.write("csstidy.exe /r/n".getBytes());
  out.flush();
  out.close();

} catch (IOException e) {

  e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking your .exe directly, you are doing it way to complicated:

```
String command = "C:/Users/BS11040/Desktop/CSSTIDY_JAVA/csstidy.exe";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

And by the way, the codes for CR and NEWLINE are `\n` and `\r` , take care to use the right slash!

Comment: String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd src/exe & csstidy.exe";

Used the above command and it worked. 

Thanks Gyro Gearless